# Windows CLI: Run command from within another command

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to write a command-line script that will be triggered each time an event log in a specific Windows Event Log is logged. Here's what I have so far:

```
wevtutil qe WebsitePanel "/q:*" /f:text /rd:true /c:1 > %tmp%\WebsitePanelErrorLog.log

set var1 = < %tmp%\ErrorLog.log

C:\bmail.exe -s aspmx.l.google.com -t cmiller@6ps.com -f notifications@6ps.com -a "wh00: WebsitePanel Event Logged" -b %var1%

del %tmp%\WebsitePanelErrorLog.log
```

The problem is var1 is not being set for some reason. If I do this, it just returns empty:

```
echo %var1%
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're trying to write a batch script that will react to changes in a file. As far as I know, this is not possible in Windows.

Comment: No, the batch file is called each time an event is triggered... I want to take the output of the "wevtutil" command and use it as a parameter for bmail.exe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set command does not take input from stdin.  Instead of redirection try something like

```
for /f %x in ('type %tmp%\ErrorLog.log') do set var1=%x
```

Comment: This doesn't work. All this does is assign %var1% to be the first word on the last line.

Comment: I said something like this.  You want to add "delims=" after the /f  to get full lines.  Also look at "help set" to see how to use delayed expansion in order to collect all the lines in the file.  Finally do not forget to convert % to %% when used inside a batch file.